# How to calculate the integration of this?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate this integration  $\int_0^1 \frac{x}{\frac{x^2}{\frac{x^3}{\frac{x^4}{\text{...}}+x^3}+x^2}+x} \, dx$  ?

I guess it is not exist.But how to prove it?

Comment: The integrand is a continued fraction with a clear pattern. It should represent a continous function in some interval. Unfortunately, I have no idea, which.

Comment: A similarity transformation changes the continued fraction to be of the form $[0;1,x,x,x^{2},x^{2},\dots,x^{n},x^{n},x^{n+1},x^{n+1},\dots]$, though I'm not sure that improves the situation...